# VB6 .Net Interop. Passing .Net Date property to VB6 function ByRef not being updated

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, com-interop, vb6-migration

I have a hybrid VB6 (entry point) to .Net application.

In .Net I have a class which has a Date property (Date1-Date4) and is exposed and COM Visible etc to the VB6 code.

In the VB6 code there is a method which takes a Date ByRef and modifies it.

With a date declared in VB6 (dt1-dt4) this works fine, the date variable I pass ByRef gets updated, however if i pass the the .Net Date on my class (Date1-Date4) it dosnt get updated.

A work arround is to pass TmpDate to the method and then assign the value afterwards to the .Net property.

I would however like to find a proper solution as this could easily be missed as I'm replacing the VB6 code.

VB.Net Declaration

```
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Class DotNetDatesClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDotNetDatesClass

     Private _Date1 As DateTime

     <ComVisible(True)> 
      Public Property Date1 As DateTime Implements IDotNetDatesClass.Date1   
            Get
                Return _Date1
            End Get
            Set(value As DateTime)
                _Date1 = value                   
            End Set
        End Property
```

VB6 Example:

```
    dotNetDates.Date1 = DEFAULT_DATE
    dotNetDates.Date2 = DEFAULT_DATE
    dotNetDates.Date3 = DEFAULT_DATE
    dotNetDates.Date4 = DEFAULT_DATE

    getDates connectionString, dotNetDates.Date1, dotNetDates.Date2, dotNetDates.Date3, dotNetDates.Date4
```

Work around:

```
    Dim dt1 As Date
    Dim dt2 As Date
    Dim dt3 As Date
    Dim dt4 As Date

    getDates connectionString, dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4

    dotNetDates.Date1 = dt1
    dotNetDates.Date2 = dt2
    dotNetDates.Date3 = dt3
    dotNetDates.Date4 = dt4
```

Comment: Could you show some reproducing code? it would be more useful and exact than explaining it in english

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Please, add VB & C# declarations as well

Answer (score 5):

In your first code example, you pass a property (`dotNetDates.Date1`). In your second code example, you pass a variable (`dt1`).

VB6 and VBA do not support passing properties as `ByRef`. (Nor does the .NET CLR, but, interestingly, VB.NET *does* support it, see [The many cases of ByRef](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2010/01/21/the-many-cases-of-byref/).)

**Repro example** (pure VBA)

Class myclass

```
Option Explicit

Private myvalue As String

Public Property Get value() As String
    value = myvalue
End Property

Public Property Let value(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    myvalue = vNewValue
End Property
```

Test code

```
Public Sub test_byref()
    Dim x As New myclass

    x.value = "OLD"
    modify x.value
    Debug.Print x.value     ' Prints OLD
End Sub

Private Sub modify(ByRef s As String)
    s = "NEW"
End Sub
```

Comment: So is there anyway to expose a field in the .Net class instead? Currently I am exposing members via an inteface but you can't implemnt fields.

Comment: @apc: Unfortunately, .NET interfaces cannot contain fields (but .NET classes can contain public fields). What about having `getDate` return a custom VBA `Type` with four date fields? That way you wouldn't have to declare dt1-4 in your workaround.